# Research paper - section dependent variable for logistic regression

Tags: probability, logistic, reporting

In my paper, in the section methodology, I have a subsection called **dependent variable**. But since I am performing a logistic regression, there seem to be 2 (or even 3) things that could be named the dependent variable:

First you have your `Y`, which is a measured variable.

Second there is the predicted`log-odds of the probability`.

Third there is the predicted `probability` (easily calculated from the log-odds).

I am wondering which one to describe in my paper in this section? I prefer not to talk about the log-odds, since it makes no sense to make things more complicated at that stage of the paper. I wanted to say the actual Y, cause that's what people are used to in linear regression, but it seems the Y is not *dependent* of the independent variables, its dependent of the probability. Could I safely talk about the probability, without breaking any rules?

Does anyone have any experience with this? Maybe an example of a research paper/article.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think one needs a paper. The dependent variable is the Y variable (these are used as synonyms.)

The log odds, and the predicted probabilities, are what are modelled from the logistic regression -- these are results, rather than model inputs.